# InConsistent Behaviour in Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat

We installed Tomcat in Linux.  The Server is not responding after 10 to 15 requests. But after 5 mins the problem get solved and getting response for another 10 to 15 requests.

We see enough 50% Memory in Linux box and we don't see any thread locks. Also the deployments files are working properly in local environment.

Please help us what could be the issue?

Comment: What's Tomcat serving?

Comment: Tomcat serves Web service requests

Comment: You have to provide way more detail. Are those  SSL requests? Do they use sessions? Did you do a thread dump? Attached jconsole / VisualVM, and take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the amount of RAM you have [allocated to Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory#Q1). Just because you have free system RAM does not mean that Tomcat is allowed to use it. The reason it works after a few minutes is probably because some garbage collection takes place, allowing more requests to go through.